# Python ConfigParser wrapper

Tags: python, configparser

I have a config file and i want to load the options dynamicaly by entering the section and the options name.

For instance this is the config file contents.

```
[templates]
path = /full/path/to/template
```

and the config.py file

```
class Config(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        self.config.read('config.ini')

        for section in self.config.sections():
            self.__dict__[section] = dict()
            for k, v in self.config.items(section):
                self.__dict__[section][k] = v


    def from_options(self, section, option):
        if section in self.__dict__:
            if option in self.__dict__[section]:
                return self.__dict__[section][option]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Config()
    print c.from_options('templates', 'path')
```

EDIT:
The question is if this a pythonic == right way to do it.

Comment: What is your question / problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

config.py

```
;# if not applicable leave it blank

[templates]
path = /full/path/to/template
```

configparse.py

```
class Config(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        self.config.read('config.py')

    def get_path(self):
        return self.config.get('templates', 'path')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Config()
    print c.get_path()
```

this should do the trick...