# how to split a string on the first instance of delimiter in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to split a string using python but only on the first instance of the delimiter in the string.

My code:

```
for line in conf.readlines():
    if re.search('jvm.args',line):
        key,value= split('=',line)
        default_args=val
```

The problem is  `line`, which contains `jvm.args` looks like this:

```
'jvm.args = -Dappdynamics.com=true, -Dsomeotherparam=false,'
```

I want my code to split `jvm.args` into key and value variables incidently upon the first '='. Does re.split do this by default? If not a suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Since you're only interested in the the first delimiter, why not just find the match for the delimiter, with a scan of the string?  Then you can just extract the two slices with line[:pos] and line[pos+1:].

Comment: @user1371011 expected output?

Comment: You don't need `readlines()`, stores a list in memory which is unnecessary. Just iterate over each line by simply doing this: `for line in conf`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is what [`str.partition`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) is for:

```
>>> 'jvm.args= -Dappdynamics.com=true, -Dsomeotherparam=false,'.partition('=')
('jvm.args', '=', ' -Dappdynamics.com=true, -Dsomeotherparam=false,')
```

From the docs:

> **str.partition(sep)**
>
> Split the string at the first occurrence of sep,
>   and return a 3-tuple containing the part before the separator, the
>   separator itself, and the part after the separator. If the separator
>   is not found, return a 3-tuple containing the string itself, followed
>   by two empty strings.
>
> New in version 2.5.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yes, `partition` is optimized for this.

Answer (score 13):

From the [`split` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

> str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])
>
> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string. 
>   If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done (thus, the list will have at
>   most maxsplit+1 elements)

```
>>> 'jvm.args= -Dappdynamics.com=true, -Dsomeotherparam=false,'.split('=',1)
['jvm.args', ' -Dappdynamics.com=true, -Dsomeotherparam=false,']
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work :

```
lineSplit = line.split("=")
key = lineSplit[0]
value = "=".join(lineSplit[1:])
```

As someone suggested in comments: you can just parse through string once and locate "=" ,  followed by splitting it from that point.

Comment: -1 `value = ','.join((key,"=".join(lineSplit[1:])))`
is the correct way to do it.

Comment: names_with_underscores are encouraged in python.

Comment: @jamylak i switch between java and python too frequently and this is the pattern I follow :) Thanks for suggestion though !

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary The question says "I need to split a string using python but only on the first instance of the delimter in the string." and my code does the same. What you wrote, gives more explicit separation of arguments though.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'll turn my comment into (untested) code because it might be useful at a lower level than `str.partition()`.  For example, for a more complicated delimiter requiring a regular expression, you could use `re.match()` to find `pos`.  But Triptych's suggestion got my vote.

Here you go:

```
pos = -1
for i, ch in enumerate(line):
    if ch == '=':
        pos = i
        break
if pos < 0: raise myException()

key = line[:pos]
value = line[pos+1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd skip using regular expressions completely, for a simple string comparison they are not really required.

The example code uses an inline method to yield key,value tuples that the dict builtin uses to generate a dictionary (I've not bothered with the file iteration code, your example is correct there):

```
line="jvm.args= -Dappdynamics.com=true, -Dsomeotherparam=false, "

# Detect a line that starts with jvm.args
if line.strip().startswith('jvm.args'):
    # Only interested in the args
    _, _, args = line.partition('=')

    # Method that will yield a key, value tuple if item can be converted
    def key_value_iter(args):
        for arg in args:
            try:
                key, value = arg.split('=')
                # Yield tuple removing the -d prefix from the key
                yield key.strip()[2:], value
            except:
                # A bad or empty value, just ignore these
                pass

    # Create a dict based on the yielded key, values
    args = dict(key_value_iter(args.split(',')))
```

print args will return:

```
{'appdynamics.com': 'true', 'someotherparam': 'false'}
```

I assume this is what you are actually after ;)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008681/python-search-for-a-string-and-append-to-it-using-regular-expression), ConfigParser is the most straightforward way:

```
import ConfigParser

from io import StringIO

conf = u"""
[options]
foo=bar
jvm.args= -Dappdynamics.com=true, -Dsomeotherparam=false, 
"""

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.readfp(StringIO(conf))
print config.get('options', 'jvm.args')
```